# Clicking button but doesn't open window or link Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Im writing a program to monitor prices on the steam market and im building a UI in electron, the issue is that when i click a button it doesn't register.

i have tried with logging it to console or sending to a new window or opening a link but it doesn't work. I tired using an .on('click', .... as well

index.js:

```html
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote
const path = require('path')
const {shell} = require('electron')
const launchbtn = document.getElementById('launch')

launchbtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'launch.html')
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 400, height: 320 })
  //shell.openExternal('http://electron.atom.io') tried but didnt work
  win.on('close', () => { win = null })
  win.loadURL(modalPath)
  win.show()
})
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="price-container">
        <p class="subtext">Market-Monitor</p>
        <h1 id="About">By SourcE</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="goal-container">
        <p><span id="targetPrice">Monitor Prices of items</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
        <button id="launch">Launch</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

launch.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="price-container">
        <p class="subtext">test</p>
        <h1 id="About">test</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="goal-container">
        <p><span id="targetPrice">test</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
        <button id="launch">test</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If the button was to work it should open a new instance of the window with the text changed to text.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        
        <div class="row">
          <div id="price-container">
            <p class="subtext">test</p>
            <h1 id="About">test</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="goal-container">
            <p><span id="targetPrice">test</span></p>
          </div>
          <div id="right-container">
<form name="form-name" action="launch.php">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Button Name">
</form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

New File call it launch.php

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 

header("Location: <LINK>"); 

}
?>
```

Comment: the button works but it opens the php file contents and just displays that rather than opening the desired window

Comment: That may be because you can not debug a php file over your computer. You can insert in for example over a webspace and it works already. I recommend you this hoster since you already get a web space from 3 euros per month. I've been with this hoster for 3 years. Hoster: https://mc-host24.de/cmp/70147

Comment: I strongly think that using PHP for this would be unnecessary.. afaik op just wants to open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily open a new window via Javascript. Below you can see the code. You just have to do a quick query.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';"> Google</button>
```

Comment: im going to rewrite the program in angular and see if that helps ill get back to you if it doesnt

Comment: Okay, I will wait.

Comment: angular didnt work so i will now try your method, it worked but how do i get it to open in a new window and open a new window from src such as launch.html

Comment: It would be nice when you like my comment ;)

Comment: I cant help you with Angular.

Comment: im back to nodejs this issue is i really want to use the normal buttons in electron but i cant seem to get them working in any program

Answer (score 0):

Do that with php and a form. The form should have the action of the php file and in the php file you make a query if he has clicked submit and then you make a header location: index ...... etc. I can sent you a code if you want.

Comment: if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) { 

header("Location: <LOCATION_TO_REDIRECT>");
}

Comment: ive never used php so i wouldnt know where to start